# How do I add/modify/remove startup programs in KDE?

Tags: boot, kde, kubuntu, kde-4

I am looking for application which allow me to manage the startup programs in KDE. Just like BootUp-Manager in Ubuntu (Gnome).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the KDE Control Center, a.k.a. System Settings, there is an "Autostart" module that will allow you to set programs to run when you log in to KDE. On my computer it's on the "Advanced" tab, but I think the layout varies somewhat from distro to distro.

If you want to mess with it at a lower level, the files to run on startup go in `~/.kde4/Autostart`.

Comment: Thank you this one thing. Is there another things do this job that are not in "autostart" folders?.

Because I am looking for Kopete IM files but I could not find where are they. I want to disable kopete IM from start at startup.

Comment: KDE also restores your session when you log in, so if Kopete is running when you log out, it will be started up again when you log in. To change that, just close Kopete (i.e. actually quit the program, don't just close the window). If Kopete is not running when you log out, it should not start up again when you log back in.

Answer (score 0):

'In addition to [@David Z](https://superuser.com/users/2419/david-z)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/158811/114040), you can also have a look at `/etx/xdg/autostart` I noticed that some gnome applications were autostarted from here. If an application stills autostarts and you didn't find it in all these places, try `dpkg -L theoffendingpackage` and look for `.desktop` files.